# How to mock JClass call in python unit tests

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, jpype

I am new to python unit test mocking. I am using jpype library in the code like below:

```
def my_func():
  #some code
  instance. = JClass("myapp.myclass")()
  #some code
```

This is the test code:

```
def test_my_func():
 my_func()
```

Here how to mock JClass() call?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read any of the `unittest.mock` documentation?

Comment: Yeah.. I have read the documentation and Tried to use MagicMock to mock the `jpype.JClass` like `@patch('jpype.JClass')`. However I am getting segmentation fault. So I am doing something wrong mocking this.

Comment: We can't tell what you are doing wrong if we don't know exactly what you are doing. Please provide a [mcve].